# Diff постов с тегами

Tags: diff, sql

Подскажите, как лучше хранить изменение постов. Интересует, как спроектировать посты и теги для хранения изменений. Создавать отдельные сущности под это или мешать с существующими?

Comment: @хэшкод, я знаю, что ты знаешь =)

Comment: @flax, если вы хотите хранить ревизии постов в виде инкрементальных изменений, то проще хранить целиковые ревизии и особо не париться.

Comment: @Etki, тогда ведь пойдет путаница со связанными сущностями, на мой взгляд, придется учитывать очень много нюансов.

Comment: @flax

> на мой взгляд, придется учитывать очень много нюансов.

    if (post_type == 'revision') {
        // A
    } else {
        // B
    }

(можно, конечно, сделать из троллейбуса дополнительную таблицу и дублировать всю систему внешних ключей)

В приницпе, если вы будете хранить инкрементальными изменениями, то ничего и не поменяется, кроме содержимого тела поста.